# Sending an image as a Base64.encodeToString from android to c# how to get that image

Tags: android, c#-4.0, android-file

From my android app I am sending an image to C# server converting it to Base64

```
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) 
    {
    String image = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
    sendtoserver(image);
    }
```

from the server side I received a string but don't know how to convert it and save it.For help I am getting this string tell me how to convert it and save it in C#

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQ
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using `Convert.FromBase64String(string s)` ?

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx

**UPDATE** (posted here instead of in the comments, since the code would display better) 
Your Base64 representation is incorrect. For the image you gave in the comments, the Base64 representation is 339801 characters long.

I used the following code to generate a Base64 representation:

```
string path = @"C:\1XlqZF2.jpg";
Image img = Image.FromFile(path);
byte[] arr;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
  img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
  arr =  ms.ToArray();
}

String b64 = Convert.ToBase64String(arr);
```

What is the `Base64` class you are using ? I couldn't find it on MSDN.

Comment: Yes I had.When I am trying to convert that string(given bellow) giving error when converting

**System.FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters. 
  at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
  at AndroidService..ctor() in d:\ABCDED\AndroidService\App_Code\AndroidService.cs:line 24**

Comment: I tried as well and get an Exception: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array. Can you provide the image you are encoding in the first place, so we can check that the base64 encoding is correct ?

Comment: conversion code **/9j/4RngRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAMAAABBAABAAAAAAUAAAEBBAABAAAAwAMAAA8BAgAIAAAAngAA
ABABAgAJAAAApgAAABIBAwABAAAAAQAAABoBBQABAAAA0AAAABsBBQABAAAA2AAAACgBAwABAAAA
AgAAADEBAgAMAAAAsAAAADIBAgAUAAAAvAAAABMCAwABAA**
imagelink-http://i50.tinypic.com/2ujox9z.jpg

Comment: I don't have access to this website from work, it's blocked by the proxy. Can you put it on imgur ? Thanks.

Comment: I want to save that image after decodeing  inside my project folder.Please enplane how to do that

Comment: Check the following: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15460/C-Image-to-Byte-Array-and-Byte-Array-to-Image-Conv